# A pro-Lie group is the projective limit of Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

[In this paper](http://sidneymorris.net/paper130.pdf), they defined the projective Lie-group and pro-lie group to be:

> **Projective Lie Group:**
>   A topological group is called projective limit of Lie groups, if there is a projective system $$\{f_{jk}:G_k \rightarrow G_j\mid j\leq k,(j,k)\in J \times J\}$$ for a directed index set J and for finite-dimensional Lie groups $G_j$ and if$$G=\lim_{j\in J}G_j=\{(g_j)_{j\in J}\in\prod_{j\in J}G_j:(\forall j\leq k)g_j=f_{jk}(g_k)\}$$
>
> **Pro-Lie Group:**
>   A pro-lie group is a complete topological group and every identity neighbor hood contains a normal subgroup N s.t $G/N$ is a finite dimensional Lie group and every intersection of every two such normal sub groups contains a third of the same type.
>   <
>   They showed that Pro-Lie Group is a projective Lie group in the following way:

let $\mathcal{N}(G)$ denote the filter basis of all $N$ such that $G/N$ is a finite
dimensional Lie group. Then the natural quotient maps $G/N → G/M$ for $M ⊇ N$ in $\mathcal{N}(G)$ form a projective system such that $G\cong \lim_{N∈\mathcal{N}(G)} G/N$.

**Question:**
Why is $G$ isomorphic to the projective limit? i.e. why $G\cong \lim_{N∈\mathcal{N}(G)} G/N$. The left-hand side is a infinite direct product while the former is just one element from $G$.